# Pusher "No callbacks on channel for an event" in laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I wanted to try to integrate pusher with my laravel app. After I followed pusher documentation, my test say `Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on my-channel for my_event"]`. The data is there as you can see first line on attached screen shot but the that second line is a culprit reason that data on first line can't render on my blade component.  What's lacking on my code below? Anyone please comment your thoughts.

My event file

```
class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['my-channel'];
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'my-event';
}
}
```

My route file to trigger the event on `welcome.blade.php`

```
Route::get('event-test', function () {

$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    array('cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'))
);

$pusher->trigger(
    'my-channel',
    'my_event',
    'Welcome'
);

return "Event has been sent";
});
```

My blade file:

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <h6>Pusher Test</h6>
        <p>
            Publish an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
            with event name <code>my-event</code>; it will appear below:
        </p>

        <div id="app" class="mt-4">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="message in messages">
                    @{{ message }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}', {
            cluster: 'ap1'
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
        channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
            app.messages.push(JSON.stringify(data));

            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        // Vue application
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                messages: [],
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

When I trigger event with the url created in route "event-test"

And here's what I get on console:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering to `my_event` (with underscore), but your client code is listening to `my-event` (with hyphen).

Change the event name in your PHP code like bellow and it should work.

```php
$pusher->trigger(
    'my-channel',
    'my-event',
    'Welcome'
);
```